# tryParse in DateFormat in dart flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to `tryParse` multiple date formats. `tryParse` method is available in `DateTime` but not in `DateFormat`. I want to use `DateFormat` as I want to parse multiple format. If I use `Parse` method then I have to use a `try catch` block.

Currently I am parsing a single date format below. For parsing another date format I have to add it in the catch block.

```
try {
  print(DateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy').parse(line.text));
      scannedString = line.text;
} catch (e) {
  // parse another date format
}
```

I am searching for a more convenient way for parsing multiple date formats.

Comment: You are trying to verify date format from string? Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I want to recognize the date from the string and that string may contain the date in any format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want, you can easily add your own `tryParse` function or extension method that operates on a `DateFormat`:

```dart
extension DateFormatTryParse on DateFormat {
  DateTime? tryParse(String inputString, [bool utc = false]) {
    try {
      return parse(inputString, utc);
    } on FormatException {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you have a number of different formats that you'd like to try, you also could process them in a loop:

```dart
/// Attempts to parse a [String] to a [DateTime].
///
/// Attempts to parse [dateTimeString] using each [DateFormat] in [formats].
/// If none of them match, falls back to parsing [dateTimeString] with
/// [DateTime.tryParse].
///
/// Returns `null` if [dateTimeString] could not be parsed.
DateTime? tryParse(
  Iterable<DateFormat> formats,
  String dateTimeString, {
  bool utc = false,
}) {
  for (var format in formats) {
    try {
      return format.parse(dateTimeString, utc);
    } on FormatException {
      // Ignore.
    }
  }

  return DateTime.tryParse(dateTimeString);
}
```