# How to parse a date of unknown format in Dart

Tags: dart, date, date-formatting

I have to parse a string that can contain date in any format.
Currently I have set a list of predefined formats like this:

`List<String> dateFormatsList =["MMddyy",'MM/dd/yyyy', 'MM-dd-yyyy',"MMM-yyyy","MMM-yy","MMMM-yy"] ;`

Each format is tried on a given input string like this:
`result = DateFormat(format).parse(str_input);`

But there can be many more date formats than those in the list.

Therefore I am trying to think of a way to parse a date in any format with specify a list of predefined formats.

Feel free to share if you have any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: You've asked very similar questions in the past ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72059158/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71970859/)).  How is this question different?

Comment: Let me share the differences

Comment: Oh, I think you mean "I am trying to think of a way... with**out** ... a list of predefined formats." Some dates will be inherently ambiguous.  You cannot tell what "01-02-03", "01-02-2023", "012023", etc. are meant to represent.

Comment: Thats true I am trying to think of a way... without ... a list of predefined formats